# How do I reuse the same downloaded image in a web page instead of re-downloading the image again?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View in my MVC3 application which displays one of two pretty small images based on certain criteria as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<td>
        @if (item.TARGETs.Count == 0)
        {
            @Html.ActionImageLink("../../Content/themes/base/images/add.png", "Create Target", "Create", "Target", new { id = item.OBJECT_ID }, null, new { title = "Define Object as Target" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionImageLink("../../Content/themes/base/images/ok.png", "View Target", "Details", "Target", new { id = item.OBJECT_ID }, null, new { title = "View Target Details" })
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (item.SOURCEs.Count == 0)
        {
                @Html.ActionImageLink("../../Content/themes/base/images/add.png", "Create Source", "Create", "Source", new { id = item.OBJECT_ID }, null, new { title = "Define Object as Source" })
        }
        else
        {
                @Html.ActionImageLink("../../Content/themes/base/images/ok.png", "View Source", "Details", "Source", new { id = item.OBJECT_ID }, null, new { title = "View Source Details" })
        }
    </td>
```

Each image is relatively small, (about 800 bytes). However, the size of the page seems to grow exponentially depending on the number of items in the `IEnumerable`. It gets progressively slower as more and more items are added to the DB.

Is there a way to cache the image so that the client doesn't download the image every time I make the call?

**OR** If I used CSS to display the image would that be faster?

**OR** Am I misunderstanding the client altogether? Does it do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will cache the image automatically; each image will only be downloaded once. Consequently, you don't need to worry about that piece of it. You'll probably need to look elsewhere to find the source of any performance issues. (For instance, start by figuring out whether the delay is happening on the server vs. on the client.)

Comment: Ah. Good to know. I'll have to look somewhere else for the issue then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The images are cached by the browser automatically. The size of the page increases because it contains more HTML code.

I don't see how the size could grow exponentially. It should grow linearly with the number of items.

Comment: **Exponetially** was somewhat of an exaggeration. It is a pretty linear growth. Thanks though.